# How do I see that every point inside the corresponding convex region in $\mathbb R^2$ belong to this set?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization, convex-analysis

Convex set in $\mathbb R^2$.

Suppose I use the convex operator $\text {conv}$ to create the convex set of $X = \{x_1, ... , x_n\} \subset \mathbb R^2$, that is $\text {conv}(X) = \{(1-\lambda)x_i + \lambda x_j \ \mid \ x_i, x_j \in X \}$.

How do I see that every point inside the corresponding convex region in $\mathbb R^2$ belong to this set ?

To give an example: suppose $X = \{ (0,0), (3,0), (1,1), (0,1)\}$. Then the convex region is [image]

described by the inequalities:

$x_1 \ge 0 \\ 0 \le x_2 \le 1 \\x_2 \le -1/2x_1 + 3/2$

**But how do I see that these inequalities describe the convex set of $X$** ? How do i see that for example $(1/2,3/4)$ belong to this set ?

Comment: Take "corners" of this set and try to express each point in your set as a convex combination of these points.

Comment: Yes, but how do I know that's possible ?

Comment: Try to solve system of equations and look at this system.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** The set $\text {conv}(X)$ as you describe it combines two points at a time and does *not* necessarily create a convex set. To get a convex set you either need to do your operation *twice*, as in $\text {conv}(\text {conv}(X))$, or change the definition of the operation to $\sum \alpha_i x_i$ where the sum is taken for all $x_i\in X$ and the $\alpha_i$ are nonnegative and add to $1$. (See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull#Convex_hull_of_a_finite_point_set) and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvexHull.html).) That linear combination, involving possibly *more than two points*, is commonly called the *convex combination* of the points. That is what @Jihad meant in his comment under your question.

**Biography for medium answer:** I worked on a similar problem when I was in high school and failed to finish it. Years later, when I was walking to class at college, the proof of a true statement flashed into my mind. The proof was not long or difficult, but it involved some analysis and was not easy either. I soon saw this proof in a text on convex sets, so I did get confirmation that my statement and my proof were correct. However, I do not now remember the proof, and quick googling did not bring one up. But here are the statements I derived, presented here without proof for now.

**Medium answer:** Doing your operation $\text {conv}$ twice suffices to build a convex set for sets in $\mathbb R^2$, but surprisingly that also suffices for $\mathbb R^3$. In fact, in $\mathbb R^n$ only $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor+1$ applications of your $\text {conv}$ are needed. The set that results, called the convex hull, is the smallest convex set that includes all the points in the original set. That set can also be defined as the intersection of all convex sets that include the original set.

Doing your operation once gives the border of the desired set with some of the interior points but does not include all the interior. The second application of the operation then gives the interior. To get an operation that gets the entire convex hull in one step you can take nonnegative linear combinations of points in the original set, not just linear combinations of two points at a time. The proof that this combination yields a convex set is very easy. You should be aware that most uses of an operator named "$\text {conv}$" refer to this more general linear combination. [There is a theorem](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis610/convex1-09.pdf) that in $\mathbb R^m$ you need only to combine $m+1$ points at a time, so in your case you could combine all sets of three points at a time to get the entire convex hull.